# LinearLayout fill whole screen width

Tags: android-layout

I have made a reusable view, consisting of a panel of buttons.

I am trying to get the buttons to fill the whole width of the screen, but it is not working. Below is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Navi" >

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:id="@+id/layout1"          
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"           
            android:weightSum="3">

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:weightSum="8">


   <Button          
          android:id="@+id/button0"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Start" />     
  <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Observation" />

    <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Joint Integrity Tests" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Active Movements" />
        <Button
          android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Passive Movements" />
          <Button
          android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Repeated Movements" />
          <Button
          android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Combined Movements" />

            <Button
          android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Capsular Pattern" />


      </LinearLayout>   

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:weightSum="8">


      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Joint Effusion" />  


    <Button
          android:id="@+id/button9"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="PPIVMs" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button10"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Other Joints Involved" />
        <Button
          android:id="@+id/button11"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Muscle Strength" />
          <Button
          android:id="@+id/button12"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Muscle Control" />
            <Button
          android:id="@+id/button13"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Muscle Length" />
                <Button
          android:id="@+id/button14"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Isometric Muscle Tests" />
                <Button
          android:id="@+id/button15"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Integrity Of Nervous System" />


      </LinearLayout>   

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:weightSum="8">      

                  <Button
          android:id="@+id/button16"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Mobility Of Nervous System" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button17"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Diagnostic Tests" />
        <Button
          android:id="@+id/button18"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Special Tests" />
          <Button
          android:id="@+id/button19"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Accessory Movements" />
            <Button
          android:id="@+id/button20"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Palpation" />
                <Button
          android:id="@+id/button21"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Conclusion" />
                <Button
          android:id="@+id/button22"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="Diagnosis" />
                <Button
          android:id="@+id/button23"
         android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="Previous"
          android:text="End" /> 

      </LinearLayout>   

   </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I am using to import the view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Observation" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp" />

    <include layout="@layout/navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning only `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

You need to add both width & height to take this effect.

`However, if you want to override layout attributes using the <include> tag, you must override both android:layout_height and android:layout_width in order for other layout attributes to take effect.`

[Check out](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include)

Moreover, you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

[Check this one too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

However, you have not mentioned the exact problem you are facing, but still I guess if you are seeing some space left from all sides of the included layout then the following thing in your code might be the problem,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Navi" >
```

You are giving padding to it.

**android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"**

Try to remove these lines from `RelativeLayout` Tag